# BizTalk Orchestration error

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am using BizTalk orchestration to call .Net class (method) and I am getting the following error:

```
xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'g2.interop.abbyy.poc.POC_Orchestration(44aa4941-bbfb-1b34-dfad-19ca74cac233)'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: 72c5b238-d471-42b3-91cc-b92f1dbc73ee
Shape name: Expression_1
ShapeId: 8376fc71-46bc-4dba-8b33-3b9c71dfb292
Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 10
Inner exception: The network path was not found.


Exception type: IOException
Source: mscorlib
Target Site: Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
at g2.interop.abbyy.POCXmlReader.XmlReader.readXml()
at g2.interop.abbyy.poc.POC_Orchestration.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="XLANG/s" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">10034</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-03-14T13:50:18.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>14814</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>GCG-devbiztalk.gcdomain.local</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'g2.interop.abbyy.poc.POC_Orchestration(44aa4941-bbfb-1b34-dfad-19ca74cac233)'.
 The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
 If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
 InstanceId: 72c5b238-d471-42b3-91cc-b92f1dbc73ee
 Shape name: Expression_1
 ShapeId: 8376fc71-46bc-4dba-8b33-3b9c71dfb292
 Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 10
 Inner exception: The network path was not found.


 Exception type: IOException
 Source: mscorlib
 Target Site: Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
 The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
 at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
 at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
 at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
 at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
 at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
 at g2.interop.abbyy.POCXmlReader.XmlReader.readXml()
 at g2.interop.abbyy.poc.POC_Orchestration.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
 at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception&amp; exp)

    </Data>
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to open or read a file that it either can't find or you don't have access to.

Comment: BizTalk is installed on different server so I copied dll file from my local and put it into Biztalk Server local foler. I then added BizTalk resource from local folder.  So I do not understand why it cannot find the file.  Please help.  Thank you